# How to use date variables in PuTTY/PSFTP batch-script?

Tags: putty

I like to use date variables in a PuTTY/PSFTP batch-script to select files with a certain timestamp in the filename.

But I couldn't find anything in the [docs](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.64/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp). Is there a command for *PuTTY/PSFTP batch-script* to use **date-variables** or is there a way to pass *Windows Batch Variables* to PSFTP?

The file looks like this: `FILENAME_2015-06-25.TXT` (based on the current date)

---

Something like this:

```
cd /subdir
get FILENAME_%year%-%month%-%day%.TXT
quit
```

---

In a *Windows Batch File* i can easily get the current date by something like this:

```
SET YEAR=%DATE:~-4%
SET MONTH=%DATE:~-7,2%
SET DAY=%DATE:~-10,2%

ECHO FILENAME_%YEAR%-%MONTH%-%DAY%.TXT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to generate the psftp script file dynamically like:

```
SET YEAR=%DATE:~-4%
SET MONTH=%DATE:~-7,2%
SET DAY=%DATE:~-10,2%

ECHO cd /subdir > script.txt
ECHO get FILENAME_%YEAR%-%MONTH%-%DAY%.TXT >> script.txt

psftp.exe -b script.txt ...
```

---

Though note that the `%DATE%` is not really a reliable approach to retrieving timestamp with a fixed format as its value changes with locale.

You can use this instead:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set LDT=%%j
ECHO get FILENAME_%LDT:~0,4%-%LDT:~4,2%-%LDT:~6,2%.TXT >> script.txt
```

For details see:
[How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203090/850848)

---

Alternatively use [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) (that supports timestamps natively) from a batch file (.bat) like:

```
winscp.com /log=winscp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@host" ^
    "cd /subdir" ^
    "get FILENAME_%%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%%.TXT" ^
    "exit"
```

For details see:

- [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp)
- [Converting PSFTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp)

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*